# Auto-add packaging when adding product to cart WooCommerce Multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce, I use a code that shows the steak weight selection form, saves the selection data and displays this data in the cart, on the checkout page, when editing the order and in email notifications.

I also use a code that automatically adds packaging when adding any products to the cart.

These two codes have been combined:

```
// Display Custom Checkbox Field
function steak_custom_field_add() {
    global $post;

    // Checkbox
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox(
        array(
            'id' => '_steak_checkbox',
            'label' => __('Steak Weight', 'woocommerce' ),
            'description' => __( 'If necessary, enable steak weight selection', 'woocommerce' )
        )
    );
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'steak_custom_field_add', 10, 0 );

// Save Custom Checkbox Field
function steak_custom_field_save( $post_id ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

    // Custom Product Checkbox Field
    $steak_checkbox = isset( $_POST['_steak_checkbox'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';

    // Update product meta
    $product->update_meta_data( '_steak_checkbox', $steak_checkbox );

    // Save
    $product->save();
}
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'steak_custom_field_save', 10, 1 );

// Display Custom Select Box
function display_steak_custom_field() {
    global $post;

    // Get product
    $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );

    // If is single product page and have the "steak_checkbox" enabled we display the field
    if ( $product->get_meta( '_steak_checkbox' ) === 'yes' ) {

        echo '<div class="steak_select_box">';

        $select = woocommerce_form_field( 'steak_custom_options', array(
            'type'          => 'select',
            'class'         => array('my-steak-select-box form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Steak Weight'),
            'required'      => false,
            'return'       => false,
            'options'   => array(
                ''      => 'Select...',
                '300g'  => '300g',
                '400g'  => '400g',
                '500g'  => '500g',
                '600g'  => '600g',
                '700g'  => '700g',
                '800g'  => '800g',
                '900g'  => '900g',
                '1000g'  => '1000g'
            )
        ), '' );
        echo $select;
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'display_steak_custom_field', 10, 0 );

// Add jQuery script to footer - change price on single product page
function add_footer_steak_script() {
    // Returns true on a single product page
    if ( is_product() ) {
        global $woocommerce, $product;
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                var price = <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>, currency = '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>';

                $( '[name=steak_custom_options]' ).change(function(){
                    if (!(this.value < 1)) {
                        var dropdown_val = this.value;
                        var remove_g = dropdown_val.replace( 'g', '' );
                        var remove_double_zero = remove_g.replace( '00', '' );

                        var product_total = parseFloat( price * remove_double_zero );

                        $( '.woocommerce-Price-amount' ).html( currency + product_total.toFixed(2));

                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer','add_footer_steak_script', 10, 0 );

// Add as custom cart item data
function add_custom_steak_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id, $quantity ) {    
    if ( !empty( $_POST['steak_custom_options'] ) && $product_id != 5737 ) {
        $cart_item_data['steak_option'] = $_POST['steak_custom_options'];
    }

    return $cart_item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_steak_cart_item_data', 10, 4 );

// Add custom fields values under cart item name in cart
function steak_custom_field_add_cart( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {    
    if( is_cart() ) {
        if( isset( $cart_item['steak_option'] ) ) {
            $item_name .= '<div class="my-steak-class"><strong>' . __("Steak Weight", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> ' . $cart_item['steak_option'] . '</div>';
        }
    }

    return $item_name;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'steak_custom_field_add_cart', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Calculate the number of lunchboxes and package, based on the number of products in cart.
 */
function add_delivery_charge_to_cart( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    /********** SETTINGS **********/

    $lunchbox_id  = 5737; // "LunchBox ID" to be added to cart
    $pakket_id = 5738; // "Pakket ID" to be added to cart
    $exclude_categories = array( 'drink', 'bread' ); // Exclude these categories

    $category_qty_total = 0; // Total of category quantity items, Don't edit!!

    /********** LOOP THROUGH CART ITEMS **********/

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {     
        // Get product id
        $product_id = $cart_item['data']->get_id();

        // Get product quantity
        $product_qty = $cart_item['quantity'];

        // Check if "LunchBox" product is already in cart
        if( $product_id == $lunchbox_id ) {
            $lunchbox_key = $cart_item_key;
            $lunchbox_qty = $product_qty;
        }

        // Check if "Pakket" product is already in cart
        if( $product_id == $pakket_id ) {
            $pakket_key = $cart_item_key;
            $pakket_qty = $product_qty;
        }

        // Check if product belongs to a certain category
        if( has_term( $exclude_categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            $category_qty_total += $product_qty;
        }

        // Check if product, contains steak weight
        if( isset( $cart_item['steak_option'] ) ) {
            // Remove the last 2 zeros (100g becomes 1, 300g becomes 3, 1000g becomes 10, etc...)
            // Remove 'g' from grams
            // convert string to integer
            $chosen_weight = (int) str_replace( '00', '', str_replace('g', '', $cart_item['steak_option']) );

            // Get current price
            $current_price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();

            // Set new price, price is already known per 100g
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $current_price * $chosen_weight );
        }
    }

    /********** CALCULATE THE TOTALS, SO "LUNCHBOX", "PAKKET" & CATEGORIES ARE NOT USED IN THE TOTALS **********/

    // Get total items in cart, counts number of products & quantity per product
    $total_items_in_cart = $cart->get_cart_contents_count();

    // Total items in cart - category quantity total
    $total_items_in_cart -= $category_qty_total;

    // Lunchbox total = total_items_in_cart & pakket total = total_items_in_cart 
    $lunchbox_total = $total_items_in_cart;
    $pakket_total = $total_items_in_cart;

    // Isset lunchbox qty -> lunchbox total - lunchbox qty & pakket total - lunchbox qty
    if ( isset($lunchbox_qty) ) {
        $lunchbox_total -= $lunchbox_qty;
        $pakket_total -= $lunchbox_qty;     
    }

    // Isset pakket qty -> lunchbox total - pakket qty & pakket total - pakket qty   
    if ( isset($pakket_qty) ) {
        $lunchbox_total -= $pakket_qty;
        $pakket_total = $pakket_total - $pakket_qty;
    }

    /********** APPLY NEW TOTALS TO LUNCHBOX & PAKKET **********/

    // If product "LunchBox" is in cart, we check the quantity to update it if needed
    if ( isset($lunchbox_key) && $lunchbox_qty != $total_items_in_cart ) {
        // Set quantity, lunchbox
        $cart->set_quantity( $lunchbox_key, $lunchbox_total );

    } elseif ( !isset($lunchbox_key) && $total_items_in_cart > 0 ) {
        // Product "LunchBox" is not in cart, we add it
        $cart->add_to_cart( $lunchbox_id, $total_items_in_cart );
    }

    // Total items in cart greater than or equal to 3
    if ( $total_items_in_cart >= 3 ) {
        // Pakket total = pakket_total / 3 = floor(result)
        // Floor = round fractions down, rounding result down
        $pakket_total = floor( $pakket_total / 3 );

        // If product "Pakket" is in cart
        if ( isset($pakket_key) ) {
            // Set quantity, pakket
            $cart->set_quantity( $pakket_key, $pakket_total );

        } elseif ( !isset($pakket_key) ) {
            // Product "Pakket" is not in cart, we add it
            $cart->add_to_cart( $pakket_id, $pakket_total );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_delivery_charge_to_cart', 10, 1 );

// Display custom fields values under item name in checkout
function steak_custom_checkout_cart_item_name( $item_qty, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {    
    if( isset($cart_item['steak_option']) ) {
        $item_qty .= '<div class="my-steak-class"><strong>' . __("Steak Weight", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> ' . $cart_item['steak_option'] . 'гр.</div>';
    }
    return $item_qty;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'steak_custom_checkout_cart_item_name', 10, 3 );

// Save chosen select field value to each order item as custom meta data and display it everywhere
function save_order_item_steak_field( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if( isset($values['steak_option']) ) {
        $key = __('Steak Weight', 'woocommerce');
        $value = $values['steak_option'];
        $item->update_meta_data( $key, $value ,$item->get_id());
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_order_item_steak_field', 10, 4 );
```

Here I had a problem again. My site works as a multisite. One shop uses packaging; another does not.

If I use $lunchbox_id and $pakket_id, then the product ID will be the same on all sites. This is bad ((

So I have a new idea, use the product name (slug). This way I can use my functionality selectively on certain sites.

It's just not entirely clear how to change the code correctly.

I will be happy for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to change the code, **based on product SLUG, but without any succes**
>
> what I did was **change** the code to **use** the **product SKU** instead of **product SLUG**
>
> So it is a matter of changing the settings in your code, so that instead
>   of the `$product_id`, the `$product_sku` will be used.
>
> Note, however, that the `$product_id` will now be determined based on
>   the `$product_sku`, for the further course of your code
>   `add_to_cart`... works for example based on adding the `$product_id`,
>   and not the `$product_sku`

---

**This part**

```php
/********** SETTINGS **********/

$lunchbox_id  = 5737; // "LunchBox ID" to be added to cart
$pakket_id = 5738; // "Pakket ID" to be added to cart
```

**Is going to be**

```php
/********** SETTINGS **********/

$lunchbox_sku  = 'lunchbox'; // "LunchBox SKU" to be added to cart
$pakket_sku = 'pakket'; // "Pakket SKU" to be added to cart

/********** END SETTINGS **********/

// Get product id by sku
$lunchbox_id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $lunchbox_sku );
$pakket_id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $pakket_sku );
```

---

**This part**

```php
/**
 * Add as custom cart item data
 */
function add_custom_steak_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id, $quantity ) {
    if ( !empty( $_POST['steak_custom_options'] ) && $product_id != 5737 ) {
        $cart_item_data['steak_option'] = $_POST['steak_custom_options'];
    }
```

**Is going to be**

```php
/**
 * Add as custom cart item data
 */
function add_custom_steak_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id, $quantity ) {
    // Get product
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

    // Get product sku
    $product_sku = $product->get_sku();

    if ( !empty( $_POST['steak_custom_options'] ) && $product_sku != 'lunchbox' ) {
        $cart_item_data['steak_option'] = $_POST['steak_custom_options'];
    }
```

---

**So the final result**

```php
/**
 * Display Custom Checkbox Field
 */
function steak_custom_field_add() {
    global $post;

    // Checkbox
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox(
        array(
            'id' => '_steak_checkbox',
            'label' => __('Steak Weight', 'woocommerce' ),
            'description' => __( 'If necessary, enable steak weight selection', 'woocommerce' )
        )
    );
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'steak_custom_field_add', 10, 0 );

/**
 * Save Custom Checkbox Field
 */
function steak_custom_field_save( $post_id ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

    // Custom Product Checkbox Field
    $steak_checkbox = isset( $_POST['_steak_checkbox'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';

    // Update product meta
    $product->update_meta_data( '_steak_checkbox', $steak_checkbox );

    // Save
    $product->save();
}
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'steak_custom_field_save', 10, 1 );

/**
 * Display Custom Select Box
 */
function display_steak_custom_field() {
    global $post;

    // Get product
    $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );

    // If is single product page and have the "steak_checkbox" enabled we display the field
    if ( $product->get_meta( '_steak_checkbox' ) === 'yes' ) {

        echo '<div class="steak_select_box">';

        $select = woocommerce_form_field( 'steak_custom_options', array(
            'type'          => 'select',
            'class'         => array('my-steak-select-box form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Steak Weight'),
            'required'      => false,
            'return'       => false,
            'options'   => array(
                ''      => 'Select...',
                '300g'  => '300g',
                '400g'  => '400g',
                '500g'  => '500g',
                '600g'  => '600g',
                '700g'  => '700g',
                '800g'  => '800g',
                '900g'  => '900g',
                '1000g'  => '1000g'
            )
        ), '' );
        echo $select;
        echo '</div>';
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                console.log('it works 1');

                var price = <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>, currency = '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>';

                $( '[name=steak_custom_options]' ).change(function(){
                    if (!(this.value < 1)) {
                        var dropdown_val = this.value;
                        var remove_g = dropdown_val.replace( 'g', '' );
                        var remove_double_zero = remove_g.replace( '00', '' );

                        var product_total = parseFloat( price * remove_double_zero );

                        // For single product page
                        $( '.entry-summary .woocommerce-Price-amount' ).html( currency + product_total.toFixed(2));

                        // quick-view-custom-price
                        $( '.quick-view-custom-price .woocommerce-Price-amount' ).html( currency + product_total.toFixed(2));
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'display_steak_custom_field', 10, 0 );

/**
 * Add as custom cart item data
 */
function add_custom_steak_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id, $quantity ) {
    // Get product
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

    // Get product sku
    $product_sku = $product->get_sku();

    if ( !empty( $_POST['steak_custom_options'] ) && $product_sku != 'lunchbox' ) {
        $cart_item_data['steak_option'] = $_POST['steak_custom_options'];
    }

    return $cart_item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_steak_cart_item_data', 10, 4 );

/**
 * Add custom fields values under cart item name in cart
 */
function steak_custom_field_add_cart( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {    
    if( is_cart() ) {
        if( isset( $cart_item['steak_option'] ) ) {
            $item_name .= '<div class="my-steak-class"><strong>' . __("Steak Weight", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> ' . $cart_item['steak_option'] . '</div>';
        }
    }

    return $item_name;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'steak_custom_field_add_cart', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Calculate the number of lunchboxes and package, based on the number of products in cart.
 */
function add_delivery_charge_to_cart( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    /********** SETTINGS **********/

    $lunchbox_sku  = 'lunchbox'; // "LunchBox SKU" to be added to cart
    $pakket_sku = 'pakket'; // "Pakket SKU" to be added to cart

    $exclude_categories = array( 'drink', 'bread' ); // Exclude these categories

    /********** END SETTINGS **********/

    // Get product id by sku
    $lunchbox_id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $lunchbox_sku );
    $pakket_id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $pakket_sku );

    $category_qty_total = 0; // Total of category quantity items, Don't edit!!

    /********** LOOP THROUGH CART ITEMS **********/

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {     
        // Get product id
        $product_id = $cart_item['data']->get_id();

        // Get product quantity
        $product_qty = $cart_item['quantity'];

        // Check if "LunchBox" product is already in cart
        if( $product_id == $lunchbox_id ) {
            $lunchbox_key = $cart_item_key;
            $lunchbox_qty = $product_qty;
        }

        // Check if "Pakket" product is already in cart
        if( $product_id == $pakket_id ) {
            $pakket_key = $cart_item_key;
            $pakket_qty = $product_qty;
        }

        // Check if product belongs to a certain category
        if( has_term( $exclude_categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            $category_qty_total += $product_qty;
        }

        // Check if product, contains steak weight
        if( isset( $cart_item['steak_option'] ) ) {
            // Remove the last 2 zeros (100g becomes 1, 300g becomes 3, 1000g becomes 10, etc...)
            // Remove 'g' from grams
            // convert string to integer
            $chosen_weight = (int) str_replace( '00', '', str_replace('g', '', $cart_item['steak_option']) );

            // Get current price
            $current_price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();

            // Set new price, price is already known per 100g
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $current_price * $chosen_weight );
        }
    }

    /********** CALCULATE THE TOTALS, SO "LUNCHBOX", "PAKKET" & CATEGORIES ARE NOT USED IN THE TOTALS **********/

    // Get total items in cart, counts number of products & quantity per product
    $total_items_in_cart = $cart->get_cart_contents_count();

    // Total items in cart - category quantity total
    $total_items_in_cart -= $category_qty_total;

    // Lunchbox total = total_items_in_cart & pakket total = total_items_in_cart 
    $lunchbox_total = $total_items_in_cart;
    $pakket_total = $total_items_in_cart;

    // Isset lunchbox qty -> lunchbox total - lunchbox qty & pakket total - lunchbox qty
    if ( isset($lunchbox_qty) ) {
        $lunchbox_total -= $lunchbox_qty;
        $pakket_total -= $lunchbox_qty;     
    }

    // Isset pakket qty -> lunchbox total - pakket qty & pakket total - pakket qty   
    if ( isset($pakket_qty) ) {
        $lunchbox_total -= $pakket_qty;
        $pakket_total = $pakket_total - $pakket_qty;
    }

    /********** APPLY NEW TOTALS TO LUNCHBOX & PAKKET **********/

    // If product "LunchBox" is in cart, we check the quantity to update it if needed
    if ( isset($lunchbox_key) && $lunchbox_qty != $total_items_in_cart ) {
        // Set quantity, lunchbox
        $cart->set_quantity( $lunchbox_key, $lunchbox_total );

    } elseif ( !isset($lunchbox_key) && $total_items_in_cart > 0 ) {
        // Product "LunchBox" is not in cart, we add it
        $cart->add_to_cart( $lunchbox_id, $total_items_in_cart );
    }

    // Total items in cart greater than or equal to 3
    if ( $total_items_in_cart >= 3 ) {
        // Pakket total = pakket_total / 3 = floor(result)
        // Floor = round fractions down, rounding result down
        $pakket_total = floor( $pakket_total / 3 );

        // If product "Pakket" is in cart
        if ( isset($pakket_key) ) {
            // Set quantity, pakket
            $cart->set_quantity( $pakket_key, $pakket_total );

        } elseif ( !isset($pakket_key) ) {
            // Product "Pakket" is not in cart, we add it
            $cart->add_to_cart( $pakket_id, $pakket_total );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_delivery_charge_to_cart', 10, 1 );

/**
 * Display custom fields values under item name in checkout
 */
function steak_custom_checkout_cart_item_name( $item_qty, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {    
    if( isset($cart_item['steak_option']) ) {
        $item_qty .= '<div class="my-steak-class"><strong>' . __("Steak Weight", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> ' . $cart_item['steak_option'] . 'гр.</div>';
    }
    return $item_qty;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'steak_custom_checkout_cart_item_name', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Display custom fields values under item name in checkout
 */
function save_order_item_steak_field( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if( isset($values['steak_option']) ) {
        $key = __('Steak Weight', 'woocommerce');
        $value = $values['steak_option'];
        $item->update_meta_data( $key, $value ,$item->get_id());
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_order_item_steak_field', 10, 4 );
```